# How to integrate phpRack with phing for automated testing?

Tags: php, hudson, phing, automated-tests

For PHPUnit  tag is supported in phing's build.xml. What to do if the automated tests use phpRack? i.e. extend phpRack_Test class

Comment: Please note that I want to use both phing and phpRack with Hudson/Jenkins. So, please consider this before helping me out. Thanks!

Comment: phpRack is NOT a unit tester. It's only contains some integrated tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`The phpRack docs say that phpRack can be integrated with phing`](https://github.com/tpc2/phprack/wiki/Phing) like this:

```
<target name="phpRack" description="Validate all integration tests">
    <http-request
        url="http://example.com/phprack.php?suite"
        authUser="john"
        authPassword="jf7mF4"
        responseRegex="/PHPRACK SUITE: OK/"
        verbose="true"
        observerEvents="connect, receivedBody, disconnect"
    />
</target>
```

By making this phing task fail when the result doesn't contain "OK" your build will also fail.

I have no clue how you can store the resulting page with phing though.

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not think this is the way it should be done inside a CI system. It places too much restriction on the path of phprack.php. Moreover, as you mentioned there does not seem to be a way to format and store the output, which is definitely required inside Hudson.

Comment: When using the above mentioned way inside Hudson, it just outputs the source code of phprack.php. It does not treat the file as some 'executable' code. May be perhaps this file is not inside a PHP container but inside JVM. Any suggestions?

Comment: @affan Try doing the http-request your self. It might be that your web server is misconfigured and doesn't execute the php script. You need to install a web server and the php modules for that to work. requesting the `url=` in your browser has to work for hudson/jenkins to work.